# Why mark class abstract when there is no abstract method

Tags: java, oop, abstract-class

I am little confused about abstract class in java. I know that whenever there is an abstract method in the class compiler force developer to mark class abstract. But even we don't have any abstract method in the class we still mark the whole class as abstract. I am not getting the point why we can do this. what is the purpose to allow developer to mark class abstract when there is no abstract method. One can say that reason is that we don't want to create instance of that class. If that the reason then marking constructor of the class private is more suitable rather than marking class abstract.

Comment: For what it's worth, I consider this to be an [anti-pattern](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Anti-pattern). If I can construct the object by just doing `new AbstractFoo() {};` (which would work, since it defines and instantiates an anonymous subclass), then the `abstract` keywords isn't really doing much. I think there are better ways to convey the "you really should extend and override" intent, such as class names, a protected constructor, or some good ol' fashioned documentation (I know, I know, "nobody reads that").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a very useful reason for having an abstract class without abstract methods: **Providing default implementations for overridable methods.**

There are several perfect examples in the JDK itself. Look - for example - at a [`WindowAdapter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowAdapter.html). It implements the [`WindowListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html) interface (among others), but provides empty not-doing-anything method implementations. In most cases you want to register a window listener that only overrides one or two of the interface methods. Then your own class simply extends `WindowAdapter` instead of implementing `WindowListener`.

Note, that with Java 8 default methods in interfaces this reason does not hold anymore, and in fact abstract classes without abstract methods do not make sense anymore.

Comment: You can provide default implementations for overridable methods _without_ marking the class as abstract, though. If that's the only very useful reason, it's not very useful, in that it hasn't actually added any feature.

Comment: @yshavit If I have to develop such a class (for example the mentioned "adapter"), I have to think about making it abstract or not. If I do not make it abstract, I clearly express: You can instantiate and use it wherever a window listener is needed. Now I know for sure that instances of that class do not make any sense (as they do nothing). So I express this intention with making it abstract and thus preventing you from instantiating it. Code should always be written with intention and not only for technical reasons.

Comment: Then _that_ should be the reason you give in the answer (essentially, "it's self-documenting code"), not that it provides default implementations for overridable methods.

Comment: In other words, the OP asked for the difference between two approaches, and the answer you gave focused exclusively on a similarity between them.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's to allow subclasses to be created but not the main class.
I guess your class has method stubs in it, otherwise tyere would be no reason not to instantiate it. It is generally better to use abstract methods for this.

Answer (score 0):

For restricting the class to be instantiated.. Example `HttpServlet` class.. it is defined abstract but has no `abstract methods`.. We can use these methods in the subclasses but creating the class httpservlet itself is useless.. thats the reason i think..

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

> One can say that reason is that we don't want to create instance of
>   that class. If that the reason then marking constructor of the class
>   private is more suitable rather than marking class abstract.

**No** it is not at all suitable

This below example will clear your doubts , If you use private constructor , Not only your Object creation is blocked but also you can not even create a subclass of the Parent class

```
    class ParentClass{
             private ParentClass(){

             }
   }
    class Subclass extends ParentClass{
    static{
    System.out.println("Hello");
    }

  }
```

You will get compile time error saying

```
error: ParentClass() has private access in ParentClass
```

But `Marking` a class as `abstract` will block Object creation but will not block Inheritence in java

---

**Update**

As you asked in comments that you can make it protected but then your class can be easily instantiated , because `protected` member can be accessed from the `same class` as well as in `SubClass in same package` as well as  in a `sub class in another package` .

Comment: Then for this purpose I can mark class constructor protected rather than private.

Comment: Exactly.. if one wants to create a subclass of the parent class.. and create the parent too.. they would make the parent class's constructor protected.. not mark the class abstract.. please correct me if wrong..

Comment: **Exactly** Making a constructor as Protected will not block `Instantiation` 
, Hope you get the Point

Answer (score 0):

As stated, this can be to prevent instantiation. I strongly prefer private or protected constructors over this as I feel they communicate the intent more clearly.

Also, in a class hierarchy, if `class A` is abstract and contains an abstract method, that method does not need to be defined in a `class B` which extends `class A`. In this case, `class B` is marked as abstract and has no abstract members.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent instantiation of a class and use it as a base class. For example, [HttpServlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html) class, an example of [template method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) design pattern where each method already has a behaviour defined. The child class is free to override one or more of them instead of all of them.